# Java Spreadsheet API - Read Write Modify

Tags: java, spreadsheet

I need to create spreadsheet in various file format: .xls, .xlsx, .ods, csv. I want to know how can I achieve this in Java and about available open source API.

I found some API for .xls, .xlsx but not .ods. Any information will be very helpful.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: As per requirement of my project I need HTML, PDF and aforesaid spreadsheet file formats.

Comment: Just a note: you can manipulate Google Docs (including spreadsheets) using Java APIs and once your documents are in Google Docs you can a **lot** of thing with them.  We recently a huge part of our document processing/managing to Google Docs and we're not looking back.  Maybe something to look into.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r, is this locally or on a Google server?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: well out of convenience (multiple people can open/edit the documents, history without needing to rollback from our VCS, etc.) we keep the "original" Google Docs on servers (we're not working with classified data ; ) but we do checkout local backups etc.  These document can at least be exported to *.xls, .pdf, .txt, .csv, .html, .ods* etc.  Maybe not (yet?) .xlsx.  But I'm just saying this is something to look into: for us the benefits were so huge that we decided to adapt our way of working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [OdfToolkit](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/)? I haven't used it but it sounds like something you need.

Answer (score 1):

For pdf generation you can use [apache fop](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) and altova stylevision to generate xsl-fo files. For xls - there is [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org) and [jxls](http://jxls.sourceforge.net) for templating.

Comment: There is a bit of work from a table to a full-blown XSL-FO document.

Answer (score 0):

For .ods I am using <strike>[Simple ODF](http://simple.odftoolkit.org/index.html)</strike>.

### Update

Simple ODF is moved to Apache. New link is [here](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/simple/).